# Can I conclude that the classifier is always good when Precision-Recall Curve above the baseline?

Tags: binary-data, unbalanced-classes, auc, precision-recall, precision

I used logistic regression for highly imbalaned data (1=0.6% , 0=99.4%)
Since PR curves are sensitive to imbalance, so i used it, but I don't know how to interpret graph appropriately.

[image]

This is PR-curve for my dataset.
basline AUC-PR is 0.006 and PR-AUC of my model is 0.05
I know that there is no magic cutoff value for AUC-PR.
I searched many tutorials of PR curves, but many said only "compare auc with baseline"

In my dataset, the AUC-PR is only 0.05 , I think it's too small to claim that the model is good. However, it is 10 times bigger than basline auc, then can I conclude that the model is good?

Are there any reference that can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's above baseline, but as you say the absolute numbers are still tiny, so it's still a "bad" model. The highest precision you're able to reach, for *any* cutoff, is ~0.17. For useful models you typically want to see precision values >0.7. It's possible that your classes are just too ridiculously imbalanced for this to be feasible though.

Maybe start by asking yourself "What is it that I'm trying to do with this model?", since this will help indicate the levels of precision and recall needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was really helpful!!